# Powershell split gives error

Tags: regex, powershell, split

I'm trying to replace one piece of text in a config file if it doesn't match a parameter. 
I read in the file for the key phrase

```
 $list = @((get-content client.cfg) | where { $_ -match "node_name(.*)" } )
 $s = $list.split()
```

I'm borrowing the parse configuration, but have no idea what class $list is. The split() function gives an error but $s is assigned. The assignment is weird. The regex should give two results but the the $s array has too many fields and I get a system object error.

How can I just $list as a simple text array with the two matches of the regex?

Comment: Note - every powershell variable has and underlying .NET type so you can call `$myvar.GetType().FullName` to find out what it is. Sometimes its an array so you can do `$myvar[0].GetType().FullName`. Not all objects in the array may be the same type though. Sending to the object to `Get-Member` will also help.

Answer (score 2):

To find out what methods are available, and to determine what type of object you're working with, use the Get-Member cmdlet:

```
$list | gm
```

In this case, it's probably a string.

The .split() method on a string needs some sort of argument, as far as I'm aware.  See the documentation on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Comment: $s = $list -split ' '
this is the way the split function should work. That's the answer.

Comment: It did work but it threw a warning:
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method nam
ed 'split'.
At line:1 char:17
+ $s = $line.split <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (split:String) [], RuntimeExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound